# how to search google groups threads using rest calls?

Tags: rest, google-groups, google-groups-api

I've tried searching for an API on google groups, but to no avail. I wish to search a Google group and get back the relevant info so that I can update to a website. Is there a way to perform this? I'm fairly new to coding,so some example code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code by editing your question and then we will be more able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to read messages/threads from a Google Group. If you have a Gmail user that is a member of the group and receives group email, you can use the Gmail API to read those messages. Additionally, it's unclear what you want to do with the group data but it is possible to [embed Google Groups in web pages](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1191206?hl=en).

Comment: I think web scraping is the only solution.